# Read HTML element values via PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to read element values from a HTML document via a PHP script.

currently I have the following code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($filename);
$xpath = new DOMXPATH($doc);
$div = $xpath->query('//div[@class="psrch-FullResult"]');
$div = $div->item(0);
echo $doc->saveXML($div);
```

This code prints the HTML code of item 0 onto the webpage.

**I have two problems to solve**

**firstly:**
I would like to inspect the printed elements' children properties/ elements.

the children are located in `<div id=ContactInfo>`
inside of which is a `<ul id=MiniContactCard>`
inside of which is a `<li id=NameField>`
who's value I am trying to read.

Are you able to help show me how to navigate through these lower level Elements?

**secondly:**
I would like to add an additional condition to the xpath->query. The class can be either:

- psrch-FullResult (as shown) OR
- psrch-FirstFullResult

Thank you for your help, Kind Regards
Jordan

Answer (score 0):

Try [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) is very easy to use and you will find examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add libxml_use_internal_errors before loadHTMLFile

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTMLFile($filename);
```

Enjoy your code!